# Consulta! duda en SQLServer como unir columnas con los mismos tipos de datos, en una sola

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

Buen día! Estoy empezando a programar en vb.net y me encontré con un problema.

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que simulo que tengo 3 operaciones que me generan ingresos.

> En una misma base de datos generé 3 tablas (`tabla1, tabla2, tabla3`) y las 3 tienen las mismas columnas: `SERIE , OPERACION Y MONTO`.
>   **SERIE** como *idKey*, **OPERACION** es un dato fijo que es diferente por cada operacion: *OP1, OP2 y OP3* y el **MONTO** que es un *decimal (10,2)*. Todos tienen la misma configuración

Ahora mi duda es, luego de probar el programa y agregar datos. Esperaba que al consultar en sql (de momento uso el generador de consultas de visual studio) me arroje alguna especie de tabla de 3 columnas con todos los valores y al final la suma de los montos.

Pero en vez de eso, me arroja 9 Columnas, las 3 de cada tabla.
y no sé como buscar esta duda directamente en Google.

Espero me puedan ayudar, disculpen si es algo simple, recien ando aprendiendo! Gracias.

Comment: Los datos provienen de una o varias tablas? de ser así puedes usar la sentencia JOIN.
Si no es tu caso e encontrado unos que tienen un problema similar en el SO inglés:
1- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739841/mysql-combine-two-columns-into-one-column/22739860
2- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427764/concatenate-two-database-columns-into-one-resultset-column
Si tampoco encuentras la solución a tu problema en estos links entoonces no estoy entendiendo bién tu problema ':D
Ojalá pudiera ser de más ayuda.

Comment: Hola, puedes poner los nombres de las tablas? entiendo que son 3. gracias!

Comment: Es importante tambien que pongas la consulta que estás ejecutando, para que podamos ver donde puedes estar cometiendo el error.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y asegurate de que tu pregunta sigue las pautas que recomiendan para que puedas conseguir ayuda y no te la cierren por falta de info.

Comment: Lo más seguro es que estés usando `JOIN` cuando deberías de estar usando `UNION ALL`. Pero eso es algo que no sabemos sin tener más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

Esto parece un problema desde el diseño. Es algo normal con principiantes, por lo que no debes preocuparte, sino aprender.

Si tienes 3 tablas idénticas y cada una de ellas tiene una columna (se prefiere el término columna a campo, así como fila en vez de registro) con un dato fijo. Lo más probable es que deberían de ser una sola tabla, y la columna fija será variable dependiendo del tipo de operación.

Por lo pronto, empecemos a resolver el problema inmediato. Si te está arrojando 9 columnas, presiento que tu código es similar a esto.

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla1 t1
JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t1.serie = t2.serie
JOIN tabla3 t3 ON t1.serie = t3.serie;

--Lo cual es equivalente a esto
SELECT t1.serie, t1.operacion, t1.monto,
       t2.serie, t2.operacion, t2.monto,
       t3.serie, t3.operacion, t3.monto
FROM tabla1 t1
JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t1.serie = t2.serie
JOIN tabla3 t3 ON t1.serie = t3.serie;
```

Eso generaría que traiga todas las columnas de cada tabla y por lo tanto se repetirán. La instrucción JOIN lo que hace es agregar columnas mediante una condición para definir cuales filas aparecen.

Para anexar filas, lo que necesitamos usar son los operadores de conjuntos (`UNION`, `UNION ALL`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`). Tanto `UNION` como `UNION ALL` anexan filas, pero cuando se usa sólo `UNION` se eliminan duplicados (y eso es más costoso). Por lo tanto, lo mejor es evitarlo a menos que se busque esa funcionalidad. De tal forma, el código podría quedar así.

```
SELECT t1.serie, t1.operacion, t1.monto
FROM tabla1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.serie, t2.operacion, t2.monto
JOIN tabla2 t2 
UNION ALL
SELECT t3.serie, t3.operacion, t3.monto
JOIN tabla3 t3;
```

Esto, a su vez, se puede convertir en una vista para facilitar su consulta.

```
CREATE VIEW vOperaciones
AS
SELECT t1.serie, t1.operacion, t1.monto
FROM tabla1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.serie, t2.operacion, t2.monto
JOIN tabla2 t2 
UNION ALL
SELECT t3.serie, t3.operacion, t3.monto
JOIN tabla3 t3;
```

Y la consulta de la misma queda como

```
SELECT serie, operacion, monto
FROM vOperaciones;
```

Para evitar todo ese trabajo adicional, siempre será mejor mantener todo en una sola tabla y hacer las cosas bien desde un inicio.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta es unir los campos y convertirlos en uno solo?, esta seria una alternativa

```
select substring(City,0,3)+substring(CompanyName,0,3) as id,CompanyName,City from Customers
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]